# Custom Twitter Field without template?

Tags: 8

What are my options for displaying a field from a custom content type, in the form of a tweet embed.
Preferably, the field would be a URL to the tweet. I know it can be be done with a custom field template but I was hoping to leverage Display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [twitter embed module](https://www.drupal.org/project/twitter_embed)

> Simple embed of Twitter widgets, without OAuth.
>
> Features Expose Twitter widgets with Block and FieldFormatter. Covered
>   widgets: Timeline, Button.